# Cross-Platform Template In C# For Windows, MacOS & Linux

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, webview, eto

I have one website URL : https://web.url.com/#/login.

I need to create web view in C# for it. The web view must be loaded and It can be used cross-platforms (i.e.: Windows, Linux & MacOS).

I have tried **ETO Forms** extension provided by Visual Studio. But web view was not loaded for above URL and only white screen I was getting.I have also tried to load by changing my URL to https://web.url.com/login & https://web.url.com/. But I came without success.

Is there any other extensions (Of Visual Studio) or scaffolding templates in C# by which I can develop web view in C# and make it to be used in Windows, MacOS & Linux.

If yes, Please suggest a names of it.

Comment: Yes there are other cross-platform frameworks.

Comment: @Smartis Can you suggest a names of it?